# webview_flutter how to add header parameter when url changes

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, webview-flutter

I use webview_flutter plugin in my flutter app. How can I add header parameter when url changes and how can I and how can I track url change? That's my code. I tried to do it using a loadurl in navigationDelegate, but it doesn't work. How can I do that? Please, help

```
String URL = 'https://...../login-app?authkey=${globals.authkey}&test=1';
  WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
body: WebView(
        // initialUrl: 'https://...../login-app?authkey=${globals.authkey}',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _controller.complete(webViewController);
          webViewController.loadUrl(URL,headers: {"SB-app": "iphone"},);
        },
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) async {
          print('allowing navigation to $request');
          if(request.url.contains('driver/chat') || request.url.contains('driver/on-map') || request.url.contains('driver/passanger-form') || request.url.contains('driver/login')) {
            _webViewController.loadUrl(request.url, headers: {"SB-app": "iphone"});
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) async {
          print('Page started loading: $url');
        },
        onPageFinished: (String url) async {
          print('Page finished loading: $url');
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

You should return `NavigationDecision.prevent` inside your `if` statement of the `navigationDelegate` event in order to prevent the current navigation and for allowing your new navigation request with that header value.
However, this won't work on iOS, because using the `webview_plugin` plugin, the `NavigationRequest` doesn't have info about the request headers, so you will end up in a loop cycle because you don't know if, for that request, your header has been already set or not.

So, for your use case, you can use my [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin using the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` event (that is the same `navigationDelegate`  event for `webview_flutter`) which contains much more info about the request and not just the URL String. To be able to listen this event, you need to set the `useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true` WebView option.

Here is a simple example using https://github.com/flutter as URL. Try, with both Android and iOS, to navigate to the main flutter repository, the samples repository, or the plugins repository:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  if (Platform.isAndroid) {
    await AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

  runApp(MaterialApp(home: new MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

  InAppWebViewGroupOptions options = InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
    crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
      useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true
    ),
    android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useHybridComposition: true,
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("InAppWebView Example")),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  InAppWebView(
                    initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(url: Uri.parse("https://github.com/flutter")),
                    initialOptions: options,
                    shouldOverrideUrlLoading: (controller, navigationAction) async {
                      var request = navigationAction.request;
                      var url = request.url;
                      var isUrlMatching = url != null && (url.path.contains('flutter/flutter') || url.path.contains('flutter/samples') || url.path.contains('flutter/plugins'));

                      if(isUrlMatching) {

                        if (request.headers != null && request.headers!["SB-app"] != null) {
                          print('header already set! Allow the current navigation request');
                          return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                        }
                        else {
                          if (request.headers == null) {
                            request.headers = {};
                          }
                          print('Header not found! Set the "SB-app" header');
                          request.headers!["SB-app"] = "iphone";
                          print('Make load request with "SB-app" header');
                          controller.loadUrl(urlRequest: request);

                          print('and cancel the current navigation request');
                          return NavigationActionPolicy.CANCEL;
                        }

                      }

                      // always allow all the other requests
                      return NavigationActionPolicy.ALLOW;
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
        ])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With this solution I can pass a basic auth to every url I visit.

```
return InAppWebView(
  initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
     url: Uri.parse("https://your-url.com"),
  ),
  initialOptions: options,
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
    _webview_controller = controller;
  },
  onReceivedHttpAuthRequest: (InAppWebViewController controller,  challenge) async {
  return HttpAuthResponse(username: "username", password: "password", action: HttpAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);
                    },
);
```